# Reading a file from database binary column (postgresql) in memory without having to save and open the file in the filesystem

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, io

I'm using Python 3.4. I have a binary column in a my postgresql database with some files and I need to retrieve it from the database and read it... the problem is that for this to work, I first have to (1) open a new file in the filesystem with 'wb', (2) write the contents of the binary column and then (3) read() the filesystem file with 'rb'.

I would like to skip this whole process... I just wanto to get the file from the database, into a variable and use it AS IF IT WAS OPENED from the filesystem...

How can I do that? I already tried BytesIO and it does not work...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: bytes(file)